# Is it possible to expand a RAID 0+1 created with mdadm?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have this raid, it is a raid01 (a mirror of two stripes).

This is the original situation:

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] 
     
md0 : active raid1 md4[3](S) md3[2](S) md2[1] md1[0]
      31174656 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md2 : active raid0 vde2[1] vdd2[0]
      31192064 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
      
md1 : active raid0 vdc2[1] vdb2[0]
      31192064 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

I try to grow the raid adding two other md (raid0) the situation now is this:

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] 
md4 : active raid0 vdh2[1] vda2[0]
      52145152 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
      
md3 : active raid0 vdg2[1] vdf2[0]
      52145152 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
      
md0 : active raid1 md4[3](S) md3[2](S) md2[1] md1[0]
      31174656 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md2 : active raid0 vde2[1] vdd2[0]
      31192064 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
      
md1 : active raid0 vdc2[1] vdb2[0]
      31192064 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

When I try to grow:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max
mdadm: component size of /dev/md0 unchanged at 31174656K
```

My question is "is it possible to expand raid01 online or at least offline using `mdadm`?"

With raid5 and raid10, it is possible (I did it many times, without rebooting, online)

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "solution", the answer is NO.
Is not possible to grow a raid1 array, so is not
possible to grow a raid 0+1 array.
The solutions are two:

a)using a raid10 which is similar and support growing online

b)create a new array 0+1 with bigger disk, create lvm+ext4 on new array and then copy with rsync from old array, recreate the initrd and reinstall grub
this can only be done offline with livecd